# Async function returns promise after .then

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, node-fetch

In my code, I have an async function that returns a promise.I am aware that this question has been asked before, however none of the solutions worked.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return (await response.json());
}
getData().then( // wait until data fetched is finished
  console.log(getData())
)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly is not working? What is the desired result?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. I guess you want `getData().then(console.log)` or `getData().then(data => console.log(data))`.

Comment: @WaisKamal I am attempting to use the response outside of the function

Comment: The `then` function takes **callable functions** as arguments, see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Your example is exactly like [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/#2-fetching-json) but you are *not* passing a callable function but a value (the return of `console.log()`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just getting a little bit confused with the syntax of the `.then()` callback.

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return (await response.json());
}
getData().then(data => { // Notice the change here
  console.log(data)

  // Now within this block, "data" is a completely normal variable
  // use it as you wish
})
```

---

###### This answer similar in *meaning* to Guerric's, but hopefully presented in a more beginner-friendly way :)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the useless `await` and just pass a reference to `console.log` as the `Promise` callback:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  return response.json();
}

getData().then(console.log);
```

If you don't have more control flow in `getData`, you might not need `async`/`await` at all:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

function getData() {
  return fetch(url).then(x => x.json());
}

getData().then(console.log);
```

Comment: This logs the value. However, I am attempting to set it as a variable. Is there a way to do so? sorry if this is a dumb question I'm fairly new to javascript

Comment: @Arjinoodles it is not possible to move the value from inside the callback to outside the callback without making the outside context async as well.

Comment: Trying to "take the variable out of the function" is often an anti-pattern. When writing asynchronous code in JavaScript you write a chain of asynchronous operations which leads to a final "side-effect" like filling an HTTP response, writing to a file or whatever. You should be able to achieve what you want without trying that.